# If status = 0 show this image in listBox

Tags: c#, wcf, listbox, windows-phone

I have a Windows Phone application which gets data from a SQL server with WCF.
The data gets into a ListBox and there is a column with the name Status.
The column status, need to show images instead of numbers, right know i shows 0 for succes, 1 for warning, 2 alarm.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks.

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using NSSPhoneApp.NSSServiceReference;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace NSSPhoneApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
        }

        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NSSServiceClient client = new NSSServiceClient();
            client.GetAllServer_LogsCompleted +=
                new EventHandler<GetAllServer_LogsCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetAllServer_LogsCompleted);
            client.GetAllServer_LogsAsync();
        }

        void client_GetAllServer_LogsCompleted(object sender, GetAllServer_LogsCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                lst.ItemsSource = e.Result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml only ContentPanel**

```
    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ListBox Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,6" Name="lst" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" Margin="12,0,12,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="12,0,12,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IP}" Margin="12,0,12,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Task}" Margin="12,0,12,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" Margin="12,0,12,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}" Margin="12,0,12,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Not to be a pedant, but shouldn't your title be '.. status == 0 ..'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested you will have to figure out how to show the image properly.

```
listBox.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Status: ", Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(status == "0" ? "succes.png" : status == "1" ? "warning.png" : "alarm.png") });
```